# Dynamical Systems with Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems

Let 
\begin{equation*}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
0.4 & -0.3\\
0.4 & 1.2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
a) I found the eigenvalues to be $1$ and $0.6$, with corresponding eigenvectors $(-1/2,1)$ (for $1$) and $(-3/2,1)$ (for $0.6$).

b) Is A diagonalizable? I said yes because there are two linearly independent eigenvectors.

c) Express $x_0=(-1,-2)$ as a linear combination of eigenvectors of A (I did this, you solve it and get $(-4,-2)$.

d) Use you answer to (b) to describe the long-term behavior or $A^nx_0$, that is predict the value of $A^nx_0$ when $n$ is large. (I did this, and since one eigenvalue is $<1$, and the other is $1,$ you end up with just the vector $(2,-4)$.

e) How would your answer to (d) change if we used a different initial vector $x_0$?  This is where I'm stuck. I know that the component of $x_0$ in the direction of the eigenvector of $1$ remains constant and the component in the direction of the eigenvector of $0.6$ keeps getting smaller and eventually fades away entirely, but how do I answer that directly to the question? How do I frame the answer in other words?

Comment: If the eigenvalues are both positive it is not a saddle point. It is just an unstable system.

Comment: Yes, right I've made that change, thanks. Only a saddle point if one eigenval>1 and another <1, but none are >1. But what is (e) asking? Is what I added at the very end correct? @B.A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are distinct real eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, $A$ can be written as $\lambda_1P_1+\lambda_2P_2$, where $P_1$ and $P_2$ are projections onto the respective eigenspaces such that $P_1P_2=P_2P_1=0$. With this decomposition, we have $A^n=\lambda_1^nP_1+\lambda_2^nP_2$. Since $\lambda_1=1$ and $|\lambda_2|\lt1$, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}A^n=P_1$$ that is, in the long term, $A^nx_0$ approaches the projection of $x_0$ onto the eigenvector of $1$. Basically, under repeated multiplication by $A$, the component of $x_0$ in the direction of the eigenvector of $1$ remains constant and the component in the direction of the eigenvector of $0.6$ keeps getting smaller and ventually fades away entirely.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but how do I frame the answer to part (e)?  Except for vectors on the axis of the eigenvector for 0.6, all initial points go to a multiple of the eigenvector for 1. Is this how I frame the answer? I'm confused.

Comment: Does this happen no matter what I choose for the initial vector, so my last comment is the answer?

Comment: @John Yes, everything converges to a multiple of an eigenvector of $1$, which, other than $0$, *is* an eigenvector of $1$. However, you can do better than that and say exactly which multiple it will be by using the above projection decomposition. So, you could say that the only thing that changes with a different initial vector is the scalar factor.